# Neovim keeps reverting shiftwidth size after `after/ftplugin`

Tags: neovim, tab-characters, softtabstop

I like to code with 4 spaces as a tab.

I added this to `after/ftplugin/sass.vim`:

```
echom "before sass file settings"
set shiftwidth=4 " <---- Problem setting, keeps changing back to 2 automatically
set softtabstop=4
set expandtab
echom "after sass file settings"
```

This is the standard way I set preferences for filetypes and it usually works.

I open a `.sass` file, and type `:messages` I see the echom messages printed, but then if I try: `echom &shiftwidth` it prints `2`.

After some searching I tried: `verbose set shiftwidth?` and it prints:

```
  shiftwidth=2
        Last set from /tmp/.mount_nvimSdR08f/usr/share/nvim/runtime/indent/scss.vim
```

changing `/tmp/.mount_nvimSdR08f/usr/share/nvim/runtime/indent/scss.vim` does not seem like a permanent fix but I tried opening it anyways and changed this line from:

```
setlocal autoindent sw=2 et
```

to:

```
setlocal autoindent sw=4 et
```

But the shift width still stays at 2.

I tried starting it with nvim -u NORC, but then it doesnt use my `after/ftplugin` at all.

How do I prevent it from revertinf shiftwidth back to 2 (make it stay at 4)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your setting to `after/indent/sass.vim` instead of the `ftplugin` directory.

Vim loads multiple scripts for each filetype, the plug-ins (from `ftplugin`), the indentation scripts (from `indent`) and the syntax highlighting rules (from `syntax`) and it does so in a specific order. This also depends on whether you have `:filetype plugin indent on` (and also `:syntax enable`) to activate all these script types.

It seems you found that the `indent` scripts are loaded after the `ftplugin` ones, which is natural. So it turns out that the `indent/sass.vim` script (which will load `indent/scss.vim`, where your current setting is coming from) is being loaded *later* than the `after/ftplugin/sass.vim`, since *all* the `ftplugin` scripts will be processed first, and then Vim will start with the `indent` ones.

So simply move your setting to an `indent` script instead. You should still use one inside an `after/` directory to make sure it loads last (among the other `indent` scripts.)

Comment: There always another layer to learn with VIM, thanks so much for that detailed answer, a great help!

Comment: I would call this a bug. I think the indent script should not set the shiftwidth setting. That should be set (if at all) as a filetype plugin.

Comment: I’m inclined to agree with @ChristianBrabandt; indent scripts should use &l:shiftwidth where possible without setting it.